# Symbols on top of hline in table

Tags: tables, math-mode

Sometimes when I make tables in latex with math symbols the spacing gets very ugly with math symbols conflicting with hlines.

For example:

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            l & $\hat{Y}_{t+l|t}$ & $\hat{\sigma}_{\epsilon_{t+l|t}}^2$ \\ \hline
            1 & $2097 \pm 398.6$ & 39508 \\ \hline
            2 & $2159 \pm 548.2$ & 78230 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}
```

In this table the hat in \hat{Y} touches the hline above. Of course I could probably do something with vspace, but is there a more generalized solution to this class of problem? Some spacing setting within the table environment maybe?

Comment: avoid using `\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{` on tables there is no chance of reasonable typesetting if you scale in this way. but for space below hline use `array` package and `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}`

Comment: How should I scale tables if not using resizebox? Especially for when tables are too big to bring them to a reasonable size for the page?

Comment: dont scale them, you would not scale lines of a paragraph to get a fake justification using wildly inconsistent font sizes, so why do it to text in tables? Just choose a suitable font size and suitable column widths so the table fits. especially if you have horizontal or vertical rules they should all be the same width not some tables with rules twice as wide and twice the font size as it had less text

Answer (score 1):

I recommend avoiding caged tables.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  c
  S[table-format=4.1(4)]
  S[table-format=5.0]
  @{}
}
\toprule
l & {$\hat{Y}_{t+l|t}$} & {$\hat{\sigma}_{\epsilon_{t+l|t}}^2$} \\
\midrule
1 & 2097 \pm 398.6 & 39508 \\
2 & 2159 \pm 548.2 & 78230 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: caged tables being tables with \hline after every line and vertical lines separating columns? Mostly as an esthetic recommendation or what?

Comment: @MortenNissov Yes, they are very unclear because each line means separation. Tables are not worksheets.

Comment: Does there exist a document describing good habits regarding typesetting tables in latex? Or any other information of this type I could read up on?

Comment: @MortenNissov Look at the manual of `booktabs` on your system or, online, at http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/booktabs/booktabs.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cellspace` package, which ensures a minimal vertical spacing of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S`  (or `C` if you load `siunitx`):

```
\documentclass{article} %
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{cellspace} 
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|Sc|c|}
            \hline
            l & $\hat{Y}_{t+l|t}$ & $\hat{\sigma}_{\epsilon_{t+l|t}}^2$ \\ \hline
            1 & $2097 \pm 398.6$ & 39508 \\ \hline
            2 & $2159 \pm 548.2$ & 78230 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So if i load siunitx I should use C for the same spacing as S?